# How to use Leakcanary for Service (like InputMethodService)

Tags: java, android, service, leakcanary

My application is Keyboard IME Service, with some UI for config and testing.

`D/LeakCanary: LeakCanary is currently disabled: Waiting for debugger to detach.` comes first.
Then

`D/LeakCanary: Watching instance of ....`  (UI's Activity) comes second as I also have an activity for UI testing.

However, when I open the keyboard, there is no watching message.

How to "install" it into the Service?

A log message shall be shown for watching my Service